# Explained examples of program time complexity

Tags: time-complexity

I'm trying to learn time complexity of various programms/algorithms. Does anybody know, where I could get a **set** of **explained** examples like the ones found on [this](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/14analysis/) site (heading Exercises).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Google ["Time Complexity Exercises"](https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#sclient=psy-ab&q=time%20complexity%20exercises&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48572450,d.Yms&fp=8edc1ab5c06fecc3&ion=1&biw=1440&bih=815&pf=p&pdl=300)

see [First Result](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/compsci220s1t/lectures/lecturenotes/GG-lectures/220exercises1.pdf&ei=RhrQUYrMIcb4sga9toCoBg&usg=AFQjCNEnnOeD1SnCrqLTtjzTpn_JOHrjag&sig2=30iSPbNYy_hLt_62XzM4FA&bvm=bv.48572450,d.Yms)